# Implement PIN with BiometricPromt

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I am using BiometricPromt in my application.
Now I need to implement way for user to enter the PIN when Biometric is not available or enrolled.
I can use `.setDeviceCredentialAllowed(true)` but problem with it is when Biometric is not available or enrolled it won't show any dialog, and even if user use PIN if Biometric is available it doesn't registrate it in `onAuthenticationSucceeded`.

So now I am trying to implement negative button so user can enter PIN and I can catch it and see if user entered it correctly but I can't find anywhere if it is possible to do with default android PIN manager, so I don't have to implement any 3rd party library?

My current code is:

```
fun biometricCheck(context: Context, fragment: FragmentActivity){
        val executor = ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(context)
        val biometricManager = BiometricManager.from(context)
        init(fragment)

        when {
            biometricManager.canAuthenticate() == BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_SUCCESS -> {
                authUser(executor, context, fragment)
            }
            biometricManager.canAuthenticate() == BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_ERROR_NO_HARDWARE -> {
                //No hardware
            }
            biometricManager.canAuthenticate() == BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_ERROR_HW_UNAVAILABLE -> {
                //Hardware unvailable
            }
            biometricManager.canAuthenticate() == BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_ERROR_NONE_ENROLLED -> {
                //NONE ENROLLED
            }
        }
    }

    private fun init(fragment: FragmentActivity){
        //Some code
    }

    private fun authUser(executor: Executor, context: Context, fragment: FragmentActivity) {
        val promptInfo = BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo.Builder()
            .setTitle("Authentication")
            //.setSubtitle("Owner confirmation")
            .setDescription("Scan fingerprint or enter PIN")
            //.setDeviceCredentialAllowed(true)
            .setNegativeButtonText("TEST")
            .build()

        val biometricPrompt = BiometricPrompt(fragment, executor,
            object : BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationCallback() {
                override fun onAuthenticationSucceeded(
                    result: BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationResult
                ) {
                    super.onAuthenticationSucceeded(result)
                    val intent = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
                    context.startActivity(intent)
                }
                override fun onAuthenticationError(
                    errorCode: Int, errString: CharSequence
                ) {
                    super.onAuthenticationError(errorCode, errString)
                    //Error auth
                    if (errorCode == BiometricConstants.ERROR_USER_CANCELED) {
                           //Some long code
                        }
                    }
                    if(errorCode == BiometricPrompt.ERROR_NEGATIVE_BUTTON) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "User clicked")
                        //loginWithPassword() // I don't know what to implement here
                    }
                }
                override fun onAuthenticationFailed() {
                    super.onAuthenticationFailed()
                    //Failed auth
                }
            })
        biometricPrompt.authenticate(promptInfo)
    }
```